# Expresso Store core files

Tags: expresso-store, add-on, expresso

MY question is there core file in Expresso Store extension which is not update when we update Expresso Store extension .I want to call a hook after payment successful so i want if Expresso Store update my code not remove

Answer (score 2):

There are a few hooks available which will allow you to latch on to the process at various points. If you want to run an extension after payment has been processed then `store_order_payment_end` ([docs link](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/extension_hooks.html#store_order_payment_end)) is the hook you'd need to look to use in your custom extension.

Comment: Also take a look at the [ExpressionEngine extension development guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html)